# PHP : urldecode($str) not working

Tags: php, apache

i am watching php lynda lecture . Following is a simple example to elaborate urldecode() function but  i dont know why this is not working for me  . Please guide me whats wrong with it

**first_page.php**

```
<?php $link_name='Second page' ;
      $id=2;    
      $name="Johnson & Johnson";
 ?>
<a href="second_page.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>&name=<?php echo urldecode($name);?>"><?php echo $link_name;?></a>
```

**second_page.php**

```
<?php  $id=$_GET['id']; 
           $name=$_GET['name'];
           echo $id.'<br/>'; 
           echo $name;          
?>
```

`output`

2
Johnson // for me it should be Johnson & Johnson
and this is url string

```
id=2&name=Johnson%20&%20Johnson
```

why is it not encoding properly ? Please help

Comment: Shouldn't you use `urlencode` ?

Answer (score 2):

Its not working because you are using the wrong function:

```
&name=<?php echo urldecode($name);
```

It should be `urlencode()`

```
<a href="second_page.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>&name=<?php echo urlencode($name);?>"><?php echo $link_name;?></a>
                                                                ^^^ encode not decode
```

Also another way:

```
<?php
$link_name = 'Second page';
$id = 2;    
$name = "Johnson & Johnson";

$query_string = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name);
$query_string = http_build_query($query_string);

?>
<a href="second_page.php?<?php echo $query_string; ?>"><?php echo $link_name; ?></a>
```